# Stationarity test for count data time series

Tags: autocorrelation, stationarity, count-data, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

can someone give me an overview of stationarity test for time series of count data?

For instance, I would like to know if there exists a test similar to the Augmented Dickey Fuller or how this test can be modifed in order to be used in the context of count-data time series.

I have assumed that the standard ADF cannot be adopted since it requires an AR model that has no direct equivalent in count-data time series.

As far as I understand, there are integer autoregressive models (INAR) based on the thinning operator or dynamic Poisson model in which the rate parameter lambda follows an autoregressive process but this does not seem to me equivalent to the standard AR process.

Thank you for your help.